# Python .txt editing gone wrong, text gone

Tags: python, python-3.x, text

I tried the following:

```
def überschreiben(filename,vp, capital):
  data_in=open(filename,"w")
  data_out=open(filename)
  vpsegment=False
  for line in data_out:
    if "\thistory" in line:
        data_in.write(line+'\n\t\tvictory_points = { '+capital+' '+vp+' }\n')
    if "\t\tvictory_points" in line:
        vpsegment=True

    if vpsegment==True:
        if "}" in line:
            data_in.write("")
            vpsegment=False
        else:
            data_in.write("")
    else:
        data_in.write(line)
  data_in.close()
  data_out.close()
```

It shall change an existing code:

1. If  the parameter history mentioned, lines shall be added.
2. If the parameter victory_points is mentioned, lines shall be deleted, but it can occur in the following two forms:

`victory_points={xxxxx x}`

or

```
      victory_points = {
        9648 5 
      }
```

I think the algorithm is correct, but I end up with an empty .txt

Whats the fault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are opening the file as "w" first. "w" is write mode, which creates a new empty file to be written.

You should open the input file as "r", for reading, and open a second file, with a different filename, for the output. Something like this:

```
data_in=open(filename, "r")
data_out=open(filename+"_output", "w")
```

If the file needs to have the same name, you can use os.remove() and os.rename() to remove the old file and rename the new one to the same name as the old one. In the end of the script, like this:

```
data_in.close()
data_out.close()

os.remove(filename)
os.rename(filename+"_output",filename)
```

Comment: Thank you, but what if the filename has to be the same due to processing reasons?

Comment: @ThorePingpank you can use os.remove() and os.rename() to remove the old file and rename the new one. I edited my answer to reflect that.